# Most efficient way to visualise multiple KPIs?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to build a Power BI report which will update weekly. The dataset that will sit behind it looks like this:

| Customer_ID | Quarter | Spend | Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | March_2023 | 10.00 | 1 |
| B | March_2023 | 15.00 | 2 |
| A | March_2022 | 20.00 | 2 |

If necessary I can use SQL to amend the dataset before it is imported to Power BI, but it must remain at Customer_ID level.

The report should aggregate this data to track several KPIs, as well as showing their growth compared to the equivalent quarter last year.

In other words, the report should look something like this when filtered to the quarter March_2023:

| KPI | This quarter | Growth vs last year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total_spend | 25.00 | 25% |
| Total_transactions | 3 | 50% |

I can create a measure for each figure and add a card to the report for each of these measures. But in the example above, that would mean four cards needing to update each time the report refreshes, and the real report will have several more due to having more KPIs. That will slow it down. Also, adding lots of measures will get a bit messy. These problems aren't dealbreakers, but they do make me suspect there may be a better way.

Does anyone know what the best way of achieving the required result is please?

Comment: I think you are trying to solve problems that don't exist. Power BI models can have thousands of measures, without any mess or performance issues. Just get your data model right, and write efficient DAX.